# Trying to take input from stdin and convert to integer for sum

Tags: python

Very new to Python.
Trying to take inputs from stdin in the form of numbers ex. 416 2876 2864 8575 9784 and convert to int for sum of all using a loop.

Having a terrible time just converting to int for use in a loop. Would like to get a hint on the integer issue and then try to solve myself. Was trying to test my code to print the integers after conversion.

currently have:

```
import sys
s=sys.stdin
n=(sys.stdin.split())
while (int(n) >= 1):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: Gents, I am using stdin because they are inputs already generated for me on a website intended for learning. I am just trying to call them and get integers for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to use `sys.stdin` directly.  Use `input()` instead.

```
line = input("Enter some numbers: ")

total = 0

for n in line.split():
    total = total + int(n)

print("The total is: %d" % total)
```

Comment: raw_input has been replaced with input in python 3 I think

Comment: Yes it has.  I didn't want to clutter up my answer too much; if poster is running Python 3, I assume he'll respond and then I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am learning/using Python 3. I am using stdin because they are inputs already generated for me on a website intended for learning. I am just trying to call them and get integers for now.

Comment: That's correct. This worked. For my own understanding, how could I specify to operate on only CERTAIN line within stdin?                                                                                                              sys.stdin.read(line 2-5) for example?

Comment: You can call `sys.stdin.readlines()` which returns a list of input lines, and then pick and choose whichever of the lines you want to use.  However this requires that whoever is supplying the input also sends an EOF signal when they're done (otherwise it will try to read forever).

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input("Type some numbers: ")

numbers = user_input.split()

print(sum([int(x) for x in numbers]))
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but need to pull the numbers from stdin which are already there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from *stdin* and cast to int just iterate over stdin and split then cast each int and *sum* :

```
~$ cat test.py
import sys


print(sum(int(i) for sub  in sys.stdin for i in sub.split()))

padraic@dell:~$ printf "416 2876 2864 8575 9784\n123 456 789 120"|python test.py
26003
```

Or using map:

```
import sys
print(sum(sum(map(int, sub.split())) for sub  in sys.stdin))
```

Or just call read and split.

```
import sys
print(sum(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting recommended this link looking for a similar answer, the integer function works just fine for trying to take a number from stdin. This will let you work any numerical functions on the variable.
For example:

```py
import sys
sec = int(sys.stdin.readline())
min = int(sec / 60)
final = sec % 60
print (sec, "seconds is the same as", min, "minutes and", final, "seconds.")
```

This script just takes your input from stdin, and uses your input as a converted integer to turn the input into a measure of seconds and minutes. Obviously you could use this approach in scenarios other than this one, though I'm not quite sure of the extent of its use.